# Improve the speed for using NOT EXISTS and CTE to get all children count?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of `wsmp_object` (about 66,000 rows), it has the PK of OBJECT_ID, and it has parent/children relation:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WSMP_OBJECT]
(
    [OBJECT_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PARENT_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LAYER_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OBJECT_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OBJECT_STATE] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

If `OBJECT_STATE` is set to 0 to hide one object, then all its children and children of children ... will be seen as hidden no matter what value the children's OBJECT_STATE is set(it has `-2,-1,0,1`, `1` is normal state).

Now I want to retrieve all children count of one object whose object_id = -1 from this table where OBJECT_TYPE = 'ZONE' and not a hidden object.
Below is my SQL and it works. But it consumes a long time about 5-6s.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#TREE_DTT_SLM', N'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TREE_DTT_SLM;
END;

WITH _dtt AS
(
     SELECT 
         dtt.OBJECT_ID, dtt.PARENT_ID, dtt.OBJECT_STATE 
     FROM 
         WSMP_OBJECT dtt 
     WHERE 
         dtt.OBJECT_STATE != 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 
         dtt.OBJECT_ID, dtt.PARENT_ID, dtt.OBJECT_STATE 
     FROM 
         _dtt _dt, WSMP_OBJECT dtt 
     WHERE 
         dtt.PARENT_ID = _dt.OBJECT_ID
)   
SELECT OBJECT_ID 
INTO #TREE_DTT_SLM 
FROM _dtt;

DECLARE @AREA_DMA_COUNT INT

SELECT @AREA_DMA_COUNT = COUNT(0) 
FROM [dbo].[FNNC_GET_AREACHILD]('-1') FGA
INNER JOIN [dbo].[WSMP_OBJECT] WO ON FGA.AREAID = WO.OBJECT_ID 
                                  AND WO.OBJECT_TYPE = 'ZONE' 
                                  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT OBJECT_ID 
                                                  FROM #TREE_DTT_SLM TDS 
                                                  WHERE TDS.OBJECT_ID = WO.OBJECT_ID)

SELECT @AREA_DMA_COUNT AS AREA_DMA_COUNT
```

dbo.[FNNC_GET_AREACHILD]

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FNNC_GET_AREACHILD] (@ID INT)
RETURNS @T TABLE
    (
     -- ID INT IDENTITY
     --        PRIMARY KEY ,
      SUBORDINATE INT ,
      AREAID INT ,
      AREAPID INT ,
      AREALEVEL INT
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @I INT;
    SET @I = 1;

    IF @ID IS NULL OR @ID = ''
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1
            @ID = OBJECT_ID
        FROM    
            [dbo].[WSMP_OBJECT]
        WHERE   
            OBJECT_TYPE IN ('ZONE');
    END;

    INSERT INTO @T
        SELECT  
            OBJECT_ID, OBJECT_ID, PARENT_ID, @I
        FROM    
            [dbo].[WSMP_OBJECT]
        WHERE   
            OBJECT_TYPE IN ('ZONE')
            AND OBJECT_ID = @ID;

    WHILE @@rowcount <> 0
    BEGIN
        SET @I = @I + 1;

        INSERT INTO @T
            SELECT  
                @ID, A.OBJECT_ID, A.PARENT_ID, @I
            FROM    
                [dbo].[WSMP_OBJECT] A, @T B
            WHERE   
                A.OBJECT_TYPE IN ('ZONE')
                AND A.PARENT_ID = B.AREAID
                AND B.AREALEVEL = @I - 1;
    END;

    RETURN;
END;
```

The function is very quickly to get all levels, only when I add the `NOT EXISTS` part of SQL it wastes much time.

How to modify the SQL to make it more quicker to get all children count (hidden objects are excluded) of one object whose id is -1?

Comment: Try rewrite `exist` into `join`. `join` is usually faster then `exist`. this might make query become really messy though.

Comment: btw make sure you have indexing  your temp table.

Comment: @T. Peter Thank you.Above are all my sql, I am not familiar with sql server to rewrite exist into join, I tried but falied ...and it seems that the temp table also has no index.

Comment: well then create Index first and we'll see if the execute time become more acceptable or not :D

Comment: It looks like you have two levels of recursion here?  One in the recursive CTE and then *another* within a `while` loop (which will definitely have poor performance) called via the `FNNC_GET_AREACHILD` function.  For your requirement, you only need the one recursive CTE.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @T.Peter Thank you after I add the index, it consumes 1-2s now.